# Which battery does my MacBook Pro need?

Tags: macbook, battery

I've bought a used MacBook Pro (light gray, metal color, 15" display diameter), and it seems that I have to replace the battery. How do I figure out which battery model I need? I have strong Windows and and Linux experience, but I'm new to the Mac world. Is there a system information setting, or some downloadable software which tells me the battery model?

(Possible candidates may be MB772 or MA348.)

Comment: Is it a new model or an older model?  If it is a newer model than you will not be able to replace the battery your self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two batteries you have listed have very visible differences-  one clips in towards the middle of the laptop while the other is more towards the edge of the laptop.

The MB772 are for the Macbook Pro uni-body design with the removable battery.  The latest models don't have a removable battery.  I'd wager if its a used laptop its the MA348.

Comment: Thanks for the useful information. Is it possible that the correct battery is neither MB772 nor MA348? What other type can it be?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply- without knowing the exact model of the laptop- ex MacBookPro3,1 or its serial number- ex W87########, I can't say for sure what the battery would be.

Though to be honest, the best way to find it would be just google the model of the battery.  Should be on the battery itself - something like ASMB012, but its also available if you go to System Profiler and look in the "Power" section.